# How can I turn off automatic mentions (text tags of people) in my comments on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Is there any way that anyone has found to turn off automatic mentions when typing a comments on Facebook post or live stream?

I am having a problem when I type anything in a comment box on a live stream.   I notice a popup that contains names of friends while typing any words that start with the persons letters in their name.  While this seems like it would be helpful it locks up my live stream and also locks up the ability to type.   This takes from 1 second to 10 seconds to recover.  As I continue to comment this will happen over and over for every word that starts off like anyone's name.

Can someone please direct me to turn this off on Facebook or Facebook for iPhone?

I do not mean Facebook face tagging in images, that is not my problem.

Comment: Thanks for the move, i was a little lost.